# Convert quadtree to SVG <path>

Tags: algorithm, svg, quadtree

I have a (very large) grid of tiles, and a quadtree representing the user selection (a finite set of tiles). I need to create an SVG `<path>` representing the boundary of the selection. This path will have a border (the standard “marching ants”), so there must be no more than one path per connected component.

The selection may be very large (many millions of tiles), and there can be holes in it.

Is there an existing algorithm for this?

Comment: Probably, but asking for a general algorithm is not really a *javascript* question. If you have a particular algorithm and are having trouble implementing it in javascript (ECMAScript), that might be a suitable question.

Comment: From what I understand, the quadtree is just an implementation detail. As I see it, your problem is how to find the outline of a set of tiles, right? *"The selection could be very large"* What does that mean? What are we talking about, in terms of size? and what kind of size? area or number of tiles or memory or what?

Comment: The selection could be many millions of tiles. That's why the selection is stored as a quadtree, and why that detail is critical to the question — an algorithm that does not take advantage of the quadtree structure will almost certainly be impractical. The algorithm's cost should ideally be proportional to the number of nodes in the quadtree.

Comment: @RobG I've removed the javascript tag, because as you point out it's really an algorithm question.